My div doesn't change it's color when clicked upon
So i've written a piece of code where there are 9 divs and I've given them ".spaces" classes and i want them to change their color if they are clicked on. But only the first div changes it's color to red while the others don't no matter how many times i click on them.
THIS IS THE HTML
<body>
    <div id="playground">
        <div id="play-spaces" class = "spaces"></div>
        <div id="play-spaces" class = "spaces"></div>
        <div id="play-spaces" class = "spaces"></div>
        <div id="play-spaces" class = "spaces"></div>
        <div id="play-spaces" class = "spaces"></div>
        <div id="play-spaces" class = "spaces"></div>
        <div id="play-spaces" class = "spaces"></div>
        <div id="play-spaces" class = "spaces"></div>
        <div id="play-spaces" class = "spaces"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>

THIS IS THE JAVASCRIPT
const spaces = document.querySelector(".spaces");

spaces.addEventListener("click",function(){
    console.log("Space has been clicked");
    spaces.style.backgroundColor = "red";
})

I was expecting that when i click on a div then that particular div will change it's color.

id values must be unique in the document. Your .querySelector() call only returns the first matched element.

Also see querySelectorAll()

document.querySelector(".spaces") selects only the first match.


Ids should be unique per page. You should remove the id="play-spaces" from each div for that reason but also because they're not needed as you already have a spaces class.

You may find event delegation easier to manage. Attach one event listener to the parent element (playground) and listen to events from its children as they "bubble up" the DOM.


Here I'm checking to see if the clicked element has a space class and, if it has, toggling on/off its red class.


// Grab the playground element
const playground = document.querySelector('#playground');

// Add a listener to it passing it a
// reference to `handleClick`
playground.addEventListener('click', handleClick);

// If `playground` "catches" an event
function handleClick(e) {

  // If the clicked element has a space class
  if (e.target.closest('.space')) {

    // Toggle its red class on/off
    e.target.classList.toggle('red');
  }
}
#playground { width: 150px; display: grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr; }
.space { display: flex; width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: #eee; align-items: center; justify-content: center; border: 1px solid #666; }
.space:hover { cursor: pointer; }
.red { background-color: salmon; }
<div id="playground">
  <div class="space">1</div>
  <div class="space">2</div>
  <div class="space">3</div>
  <div class="space">4</div>
  <div class="space">5</div>
  <div class="space">6</div>
  <div class="space">7</div>
  <div class="space">8</div>
  <div class="space">9</div>
</div>



Additional documentation

Event target
closest
classList

